# How to get the enpoint of a request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest

REST API is used. At work, I've recently been asked to give a request endpoint. For example, I have a request api/products/product-search. How to find out what data it returns?

Maybe it's a stupid question, but still

Comment: just request that endpoint

Comment: 1. Make a request to it, or 2. Check for their documentation. Swagger is pretty much industry standard for REST APIs

Answer (score 0):

if you are using axios you can make this:

```
axios.get('https://your-url.com/api/products/product-search')
  .then(response => {
    //response.data have a response data :)
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I hope it's usefull

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetch and console log to see what are returns.
Also, you can use tools for testing APIs, such as Postman, Insomnia, or cURL.

```
   fetch('https://url.com/api/products/product-search')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```